# What is the maximum number of given numbers that still produces a minimal Sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

The minimum number of given numbers that produce a valid Sudoku with a unique solution has been proven to be $17$, so it got me thinking, what is the maximum number of given numbers that still produces a minimal Sudoku?

A minimal Sudoku puzzle is one where removing any of the given digits leads to multiple possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [source](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/high-clue-tamagotchis-t30020-135.html) I found on the [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Maximum_number_of_givens) for this problem. here's a minimal Sudoku with 40 clues:

[image]

It is not known whether 40 is optimal.